# Mongoose Query: Compare one value with another transformed value of the same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dayjs

I need to query dates in the `paidUntilDate` property that are x days later than today, where x is in the property `notificationDaysBefore` of the same document. I'm using the [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) library to query dates.

I found that I could compare values in the same document using `$expr`, but I don't know if I could use one of the values as a parameter to a dayjs `.add()` function and compare it to the other value.

Currently I have this query that gets `paidUntilDate` dates that are between 7-8 days from today.

```
const today = dayjs();
await Bed.find({
    paidUntilDate: {
      $lte: today.add(8, 'days'),
      $gte: today.add(7, 'days')
    }
  })
```

I just need to replace the `7` with the values in the `notificationDaysBefore` property, and `8` with the `7` value +1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I think I'm better off doing something like this:

```
await Bed.find({
}).where(today.diff('paidUntilDate')).in('notificationDaysBefore')
```

or

```
await Bed.find({
  notificationDaysBefore: today.diff('$paidUntilDate', 'day'),
})
```

since `notificationDaysBefore` contains an array of numbers, but I still haven't figured out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass reference to `notificationDaysBefore` like this

```
const today = dayjs();
await Bed.find({
    paidUntilDate: {
      $lte: today.add(8, 'days'),
      $gte: today.add('$notificationDaysBefore', 'days')
    }
  })
```

Comment: what if $notificationDaysBefore is an array? Would that work as well?

Comment: No, it won't. what is your expected behaviour when its array ?

Comment: I think I'm better off doing something like 
`Bed.find({
    notificationDaysBefore: today.diff('$paidUntilDate', 'day')
  })`
or something like that, but I haven't figured out the correct syntax.